# Formula to change line break to row

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

[image]

|  |  |
| --- | --- |
| a hi | a |
| b hi | hi |
| c hi | b |
|  | hi |
|  | c |
|  | hi |

In the data in column K, I want to divide the contents of cells containing newlines into rows! Can this be replaced using a formula?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
=FLATTEN(SPLIT(TEXTJOIN(CHAR(10),1,K:K),CHAR(10)))
```

- 

[image]